# Is there a way to specify the timezone in the Meteostat API to retrieve historical daily weather information?

Tags: python

I'm using the [Meteostat Python API](https://dev.meteostat.net/python/daily.html). I'm trying to fetch historical daily weather data. For doing this, the `Daily` function can be used. This function receives an start datetime and an end datetime.

I would like to get daily historical weather data with respect to the local timezone. Is there a way to specify the timezone of this datetime? If not, with respect to what timezone should the start and end datetimes be represented?

Comment: Hi! I have just posted the code for a modified Daily class to include timezones. Does it answer your question? Do you need further help in the matter?

Comment: Yes, it answers my question. Thank you!

Comment: Perfect! Would you please accept it as the answer then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, at the time of writing this answer, the timezone option is only implemented in the [Hourly](https://github.com/meteostat/meteostat-python/blob/master/meteostat/interface/hourly.py) class of the Meteosat module.

The workaround I found is to create a new class *TimezoneDaily* inherited from the original *Daily* class already implemented. I added in it the timezone conversion method from the *Hourly* class. Here is the piece of code:

```
from meteostat import Daily, Point
import pandas as pd
from typing import Union
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pytz
import numpy as np


class TimezoneDaily(Daily):
    def __init__(self,
             loc: Union[pd.DataFrame, Point, list, str],
             start: datetime = None, end: datetime = None,
             timezone: str = None, model: bool = True, flags: bool = False):
    # Inherit the attributes from Daily class
    super(Daily, self).__init__()
    self._loc = loc
    self._start = start
    self._end = end
    self._timezone = timezone
    self._model = model
    self._flags = flags
    # Download data as annual chunks
    self.chunked = True

    # Set time zone and adapt period
    self._set_time(start, end, timezone)
    # Initialize time series
    self._init_time_series(loc, start, end, model, flags)

    # Implementation from hourly.py located in:
    # https://github.com/meteostat/meteostat-python/blob/master/meteostat/interface/hourly.py
    def _set_time(self, start: datetime = None, end: datetime = None,
              timezone: str = None) -> None:

        if timezone in pytz.all_timezones:

            # Save timezone
            self._timezone = timezone

            if start and end:
                # Initialize time zone
                timezone = pytz.timezone(self._timezone)
                # Set start and end date
                start = timezone.localize(start).astimezone(pytz.utc)
                end = timezone.localize(end).astimezone(pytz.utc)
        else:
            print("Timezone is is not implemented in pytz.\n"
                  "Please use a timezone inside pytz.all_timezones list.")
    
        # Query data as chunks of one year
        if self.chunked:
            self._annual_steps = [
                (start + timedelta(days=365 * i)).year
                for i in range(end.year - start.year + 1)
            ]

        # Since datetime have already been converted to datetime object in
        # specified timezone, the TZ can be avoided to prevent deprecating 
        # warning in Numpy.
        self._start = np.datetime64(start.replace(tzinfo=None))
        self._end = np.datetime64(end.replace(tzinfo=None))
```

Hope this solves your problem!